# What state represents the loading or data not fetched yet state when using enabled with useQuery in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

```
const {isAuthenticated} = useAuth();

    const { isLoading: isTwilioAccountsLoading, isSuccess: isTwilioAccountsSuccess, isError: isTwilioAccountsError, data: twilioAccounts, error: errorTwilioAccounts } = useQuery("twilioAccounts", () => TwilioAccountsFunc(), {
        enabled: !!isAuthenticated,
        placeholderData: []
    });

    function getTwilioAccounts() {
        if (!isTwilioAccountsSuccess) {
            return <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-1/4">
                <div className="mt-4">
                    <p className="w-24"><Skeleton /></p>
                </div>
            </div> 
        } else {
            if (isTwilioAccountsSuccess && twilioAccounts && twilioAccounts.length > 0) {
                return twilioAccounts.map((account, i) => {
                    return <div key={i} className="flex flex-col items-center w-1/4">
                        <div className="mt-4">
                            {!account.is_subaccount ?
                            <Link to={"/accounts/twilio/" + account.account_id} className="underline text-gray-800 font-medium">{account.name}</Link> :
                            <p className="leading-tight font-medium text-gray-800">{account.name}</p>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                });
            } else {
                return <Alert message="There are currently no accounts in use." />
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to show the section with the skeleton on the initial page load when we still need to fetch the `twilioAccounts` data. Because I am using the enabled dependency, the isLoading is false and `isSuccess` is true on the initial page load. What state should I be using to capture no data available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start by saying that there is a change coming in v4 to this, so let's look at the two major versions separately:

### v3

in v3, queries that have no data and are not currently fetching data are in `status: 'idle'`  or `isIdle: true` (as mentioned in [@jakub-kotrs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72502034/8405310))

### v4

in v4, the idle state has been removed and a "secondary" state has been added that makes all permutations of the two states possible:

- `status: 'loading' | 'success' | 'error'`

This state gives you information about the `data` field and can be used for type-narrowing:

- `loading`: there is no data yet
- `success`: there is data
- `error`: there is no data because there was an error in the previous fetch

This status is pretty similar to the states a `Promise` can be in: `pending` | `fulfilled` | `rejected`.

- `fetchStatus: 'idle' | 'fetching' | 'paused'`

This state gives you information about if react-query is currently fetching (could be the first fetch, or a subsequent refetch).

As I said, all combinations are possible. In case of a disabled query that doesn't have data yet, you'll be in `status: 'loading'` and `fetchStatus: 'idle'`.

---

In your specific example, the use of `placeholderData` changes those states significantly. Since when using `placeholderData`, you actually have *data* to render, the status will always be `success` (as that only indicates that there is data available). There is an additional `isPlacholderData` flag returned from `useQuery` that you can use to determine if you have fake, placholder data (true) or "real" data (false). This is true for both versions. In v4, the `fetchStatus` will then additionally be `'idle'` for disabled queries, and `'fetching'` for enabled queries.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `isIdle`:

```js
const {isIdle} = useQuery(["key"], fn, {
    enabled: false
});

console.log(isIdle)
```

Comment: isIdle work in react query v3

Answer (score 0):

when `enabled: false` to get the right loading state you can test on

```
fetchStatus === 'fetching' && status === 'loading'
```